# git clone failed when I checkout my own gitlab.com project?

Tags: git

I have my private project on gitlab.com. Recently I have changed my laptop and want to clone to my new hard drive. However when I run `git clone git@gitlab.com:xxx`, it gave me this error. I do have a file larger than 100M, but I didn't find a limitation on the gitlab. And everything works fine before this. How can I solve it.

```
remote: Counting objects: 406, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (396/396), done.
Connection to gitlab.com closed by remote host.24 bytes/s
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed
```

Comment: The message "the remote end hung up unexpectedly" suggests that something is wrong on the server side.  You're best course of action is probably contacting the folks at gitlab.com.

Comment: @larsks Thank you very much. Let me try.

Comment: It is the server problem.

Comment: @einverne looks like the question is off-topic now, it falls under "This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced". I would suggest deleting it.

Comment: This is really too bad for me since I just got the same error a few seconds ago.